# Importing Monkeytalk Projects

Tags: ios, testing

I have monkeytalk scripts on my local machine.

I zipped the workspace directory and move it to server

How do I import the projects/contents of the workspace to monkeytalk on my server.

Basically, how do I open a project with Monkeytalk!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the project from MonkeyTalk in the following way.

1. Goto "File" Menu.
2. Select "Import"
3. Under "General"
4. Select "Existing Projects into Workspace"
5. Click "Next"
6. Select the root directory of the workspace to be imported.

Hope this helps.